# MySQL - Search exact word from string

Tags: mysql

I want to search exact word from string like

```
id  Description
1   This is nice pen looking good
2   This is nice pendrive looking good
```

**Search String** : `pen`

My Current query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE Description like '%pen%';
```

Above Query return both record but I want Only first record. Because **pen** word exact match with my search string.

**Expected Output**

```
1   This is nice pen looking good
```

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86c9db/3)**

Comment: As GurV has posted, regexp operator will work - but it is slow. Consider switching to a MySQL's FULLTEXT index and search.

Comment: Can you suggest me is there any other option?

Comment: If you can't use FULLTEXT, regexp is your best bet.

Comment: I dont about `FULLTEXT`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using regular expressions:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    Description regexp '(^|[[:space:]])pen([[:space:]]|$)';
```

#### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/680994/1)

Or using [word boundaries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    Description regexp '[[:<:]]pen[[:>:]]';
```

Comment: Thank You @GurV. Your answer is perfect which I want.

Comment: As GurV has posted, regexp operator will work - but it is slow. Consider switching to a MySQL's FULLTEXT index and search.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) and the `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` word boundary markers:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    Description REGEXP '[[:<:]]pen[[:>:]]';
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/KCVYK81405)

Comment: Thanks @Faisal for helping

Answer (score 1):

you can use fulltext match like as follow

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH (column_name) AGAINST 
  ('search_word' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)" ;
```

you can select boolean mode also,it return exact word in search result

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get exact word results

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE Description ='pen';
```

Comment: That is full text, indeed, but if you look closer at the question you see that the question is really about finding a word in the description.